# Sharepoint alert - In Mail Body Document created coming as Changed

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I am one issue with SharePoint Alert. When I upload the document in the library I created the Alert to send the mail. I am getting the mail as " Document Name has been Changed" which should come as
"Document Name has been Added".
There are no workflows attached to the Library. I verified the ULS logs and I didn't find and event receiver added to the library.

Need your help how to fix the issue(Email issue)

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Please change the type to"New items are added", then check if the email will show as "Document Name has been Added":

[image]

[image]

Then switch back to "All changes" to check if the alert email works well.